# How to Log the Zend_Http_Client request

Tags: php, http, zend-framework

I'm trying to log my request before i do it, to know really what i'm sending example:
I have this code:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setUri($uri);
$client->setConfig(array('timeout' => 30));
$client->setHeaders('Content-Type: application/xml');
$client->setMethod('POST');

$client->setParameterPost('PartnerID', 'xxx');
$client->setParameterPost('Password', 'XXXXXXXXX');
```

before i do the request i wanna know what i'm sending, something like that:

```
$request = json_encode($client);
Log::notice("Request: " . $request);
```

or:

```
Log::notice("Request: " . $client);
```

But doesn't work...

I can log the response like that:

```
$response = $client->request();
Log::notice("Response: " . $response);
```

Like that i can see the response json, but i wanna know the request that i'm doing.

Thank u all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the last request with function `Zend_Http_Client->getLastRequest()`. Be aware that the function returns a string and you may have to add some code to fit it in a meaningful JSON output. Add the following to your code:

```
$request = $client->getLastRequest()
// make your changes to support JSON
Log::notice("Request: " . $request)
```

The function is also mentioned in the on-line documentation at [Introduction - Zend_Http - Zend Framework - Accessing Last Request and Response](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.html#zend.http.client.accessing_last).